# Selenium Button Click is not Working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I can not get the button to be clicked, however it is working rarely I tried waits such as:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(ViewBtn)).Click();
```

it is not even waiting, it goes immediately to the next line of code which means that the button is clickable.

I also tried to click it using Javascript but it is not working also:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ViewBtn);
```

Whatever I try to use to click the button, it does not work and it does not cause any exceptions to be thrown.

This button exists in a table, in every row, and I am clicking a td that contains anchor text inside, originally it is clickable but when I filter the table using a search condition the button stops working, (clicking manually still works)

Comment: In that case can you try to click with different available locators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by dealing with the anchor text not the td, it is strange that clicking the td works before filtering results and stops working after that